# Uniform radius in an open set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, non-empty and path-connected set. Moreover let $x,y\in\Omega$ be two points and $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\Omega$ be a path from $x$ to $y$. Then there is some $R>0$, such that the ball with radius $R$ centered at an arbitrary point in $\gamma([0,1])$ is a subset of $\Omega$.
Does someone know how to prove this?

Comment: The question is not clear. If $\Omega$ is open, for all $x\in\Omega$, there is an $R>0$ such that $B_R(x)\subset \Omega$. In particular, $\gamma([0,1])\subset \Omega$, and thus for all $x\in\gamma ([0,1])$, ther is an $R>0$ s.t. $B_R(x)\subset \Omega$. But may be I didn't understand the question...

Comment: $R$ should be independent of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\gamma([0,1])\subset\Omega$ is compact.